# How to combine these several different value type to NSData?

Tags: ios, swift, nsdata, multipeer-connectivity

I need to use `MultipeerConnectivity` to send images and some set of arrays of strings to another device. On the receiver side, the API is `func session(session: MCSession, didReceiveData data: NSData, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID)`, it only receives `NSData` data. But I need to send something like this:

```
struct data{
var imageData:NSData?
var location:[String:String]?
var information:[String]?
var sliderInfo:[String]?
var questionsAndAnswer:[String:String]?
var secrets: String?
var tempts: Int?

}
```

There are many different value types inside the dataStructure, but how do I convert this custom data structure to `NSData` and then decode that on the receiver side? I'm using Swift for this project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use another way to solve this problem:
On the sender side, send the `Dictionary:[String:[String]]`, encode that, and decode that on the receiver side. For `NSData`, I send that again. Seprate it from the other data.

```
        let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.detailImage!, 1.0)

        let msg = ["clickHidenInfo":[clickHidenInfo],"swipeInfo":upDownLeftRight,"sliderInfo":slideHiddenInforation,"locationInfo":["x1,y1,info","x2,y2,info"],"qa":["what's your name","Jerry"],"hints":["hints I provide"],"tempts":["tempts you can use"]]



//sender:
        let msgData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(msg)

        do
        {
            try self.session?.sendData(imageData!, toPeers: (self.session?.connectedPeers)!, withMode: .Unreliable)
            print("succee")
        }
        catch{
            print("failure")
        }

        do
        {
            try self.session?.sendData(msgData, toPeers: (self.session?.connectedPeers)!, withMode: .Unreliable)
            print("succee")
        }
        catch{
            print("failure")
        }
//receiver side
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){


        let dict = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(data)
        if dict == nil
        {
            self.guessImage.image = UIImage(data: data)
            self.guessImage.reloadInputViews()
        }
        else
        {
            let result = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(data) as? Dictionary<String,[String]>
            let a = result!["swipeInfo"]
            print("\(a![0])")
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You'll have an easier time if you make this an NSObject subclass that adopts NSCoding. NSCoding and NSKeyedArchiver is how you serialize arbitrary data to NSData and then retrieve the arbitrary data later.

Comment: Do you mean make the struct like this: struct data:NSCoding{ /*something*/ }  ?

Comment: You can't make a Struct conform to NSCoding. It has to be an NSObject subclass.

Comment: "Do you mean make the struct like this" No, that's not what I said. I said NSObject subclass. That's a class, not a struct. You need to enlist the help of Cocoa here; you can't do that with a Swift struct.

Answer (score -2):

```
NSMutableDictionary *mutDic = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[mutDic setValue:data.imageData forKey:@"imageData"];
[mutDic setValue:data.location forKey:@"location"];
[mutDic setValue:data.information forKey:@"information"];
[mutDic setValue:data.sliderInfo forKey:@"sliderInfo"];
```